# If and if-else statement in Angular project

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

How do I write a if and if-else statement in Angular project? It's only the "else" that is returning, even though the initial conditions are true.

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  productWorth: number;
  unit: number;
  pricePerProduct:any = this.changepricePerProduct();
  result: number;
  
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  changepricePerProduct() {
    if (this.productWorth >= 200 && (this.productWorth) <= 2000) {
      return 150;
    } else if (this.productWorth >= 2001 && (this.productWorth) <= 5000) {
      return 450
    } else if (this.productWorth >= 5001 && (this.productWorth) <= 10000) {
      return 900
    } else if (this.productWorth >= 10001 && (this.productWorth) <= 20000) {
      return 1200
    } else if (this.productWorth >= 20000) {
      return 1500
    } else {
      return 0
    }
  }

  multiply() {
    this.result = this.pricePerProduct * this.unit;
  }
}
```

Comment: As long as `this.productWorth` is `undefined`, all conditions will evaluate to `false`.

Comment: Please give a [mre]; in what you're showing `productWorth` never changes from its initial value of `undefined`, so it's unclear why you'd expect any other condition to match.

Comment: Here is a link to the code on plnkr
[link](https://embed.plnkr.co/plunk/y0xhntWrj0LwFsd3)

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't show any kind of change of the `productWorth` field. Hence we can just assume, that it keeps being `undefined`, which will always result into 0.

Please don't mind me giving you a recommendation along. Remove this horror if-else construct. Instead you can do this:

```js
// must be sorted
var myPriceTable = {
  200: 150,
  2001: 450,
  5001: 900,
  10001: 1200,
  20001: 1500
}

function changepricePerProduct(productWorth) {
  if (typeof productWorth !== 'number') return 0;
  
  var floorKey = Object.keys(myPriceTable).findLast(key => key < productWorth);

  return floorKey ? myPriceTable[floorKey] : 0;
}

console.log(changepricePerProduct(undefined));
console.log(changepricePerProduct(5));
console.log(changepricePerProduct(222));
console.log(changepricePerProduct(5555));
console.log(changepricePerProduct(22222));
```

Comment: findLast is returning an error, please help

Property 'findLast' does not exist on type 'string[]'.ts(2339)

Comment: Array.prototype.findLast is pretty new. In older ES-versions it is not available for you. However, you can instead use lodash's findLast for example.

Comment: You can also declare your object in inverse mode and use `find` (or use an array of object with properties: key and value. like this "hard copy of Moxxi idea's" [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qahzaq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

```
changepricePerProduct() {
 return this.productWorth >= 200 && (this.productWorth) <= 2000 ? 150 : 
 (this.productWorth >= 2001 && (this.productWorth) <= 5000)?450: 
 (this.productWorth >= 5001 && (this.productWorth) <= 10000)?900: 
 (this.productWorth >= 10001 && (this.productWorth) <= 20000)?1200: 
 (this.productWorth >= 20000)?1500:0 }
```